# How to make fileUpload parameters dynamic in Struts 2

Tags: java, struts2, upload, ognl, struts2-interceptors

In a Struts 2 application we use `fileUpload` interceptor to get file from the user.

The `fileUpload`  has some configurations `maximumSize` , `allowedTypes` , `allowedExtensions` that can be used as:

```xml
<interceptor-ref name="fileUpload">
    <param name="maximumSize">200000</param>                                          
    <param name="allowedTypes">text/plain</param>
    <param name="allowedExtensions">txt</param> 
</interceptor-ref>
```

Is it possible to make these parameters dynamic !?

For example :

```xml
<param name="maximumSize">${maxsize}</param>
```

and let the action set its max file size.

Comment: Nope, it isn't supported yet, feel free to register an improvement in JIRA

Comment: Dear @LukaszLenart done! Please check https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-4687

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's *not* possible to make these parameters dynamic. But at runtime when interceptor is invoked you can get the value dynamically

```
String maxsize = TextParseUtil.translateVariables(maximumSize, actionInvocation.getStack());
```

The action is invoked after interceptors chain, so it can't set the value. However you can translate the value before chained result.